# Generic repository constructor

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to work with generic repositories in entity framework and came across this code below:

```
public class GenericRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
where TContext : IUnitOfWork
where TEntity : class
{
protected TContext _context;
/// <summary>
/// Constructor that takes a context
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">An established data context</param>
public GenericRepository(TContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> Select()
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
}

public TEntity GetSingle(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Single(predicate);
}

public TEntity GetFirst(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().First(predicate);
}

public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a null entity");

    _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
}

public void Delete(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot delete a null entity");

    _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
}

public void Attach(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot attach a null entity");

    _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
}

#region IDisposable implementation
private bool disposedValue;

public void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // dispose managed state here if required
        }
        // dispose unmanaged objects and set large fields to null
    }
    this.disposedValue = true;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
#endregion
 }
```

However I find it a little difficult to understand the need for the constructor created

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor that takes a context
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">An established data context</param>
public GenericRepository(TContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Can someone please explain the use of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there may be multiple DbContext class in your project, So you need to inject a specific DbContext instance to tell the GenericRepository class which DbContext you are using.

The reason you need to have multiple DbContext class maybe are:

1. Your project target to several Databases;
2. Your project is large, for the consideration of performance and maintainability, you want to split it into several modules. For Example:

   ```
   public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext
     where TContext : DbContext, new()        
   {        
       protected BaseContext()
       : base("name=ConnectionString")
       {            
       }
   }

   public class ShopDbContext :BaseContext<ShopDbContext>
   {
       public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
   }

   public class BlogDbContext :BaseContext<BlogDbContext>
   {
       public DbSet<Blog> Blogs{ get; set; }
   }
   ```

Now, if you want to query the Products, you must instantiate the ShopDbContext, and pass it into the GenericRepository constructor(IoC is a good choice).